# MVC controller action not returning JSON

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I am unable to get a json response from my controller action. The network shows as a post which is correct as I am posting a file to the server, however, needs a JSON response sent back to my view.

```
    public JsonResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file, int id)
    {
        Homes thishomes= _db.Homes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == id);

        FileUploader fileupload = new FileUploader();
        fileupload.PostIt(file.InputStream);

        return Json(new { success = true, response = "File uploaded.", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });
     }
```

JQUERY using Dropzonejs:

```
Dropzone.options.DropzoneForm = {
             paramName: "file",
             maxFilesize: 2000,
             maxFiles: 28,
             dictMaxFilesExceeded: "Custom max files msg",
             init: function () {
                 this.on("success", function () {
                     alert("Added file");
                 })
             }
        };
```

Can anyone see an this issue?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Debug your code!

Comment: No errors, my view returns fine

Comment: Your not returning a view- its a `JsonResult`!

Comment: I am not getting any error, just no response

Comment: Of course you are getting an error. You have not even shown hbow you call this method in in the view. Use you browser tools to inspect the response. Debug your code!!

Comment: I have updated question. I am using a plugin called dropzonejs

Answer (score 0):

Try to write [HttpPost] attribute over your action. Also "*The network shows as a post which is correct*"  if its post then you don't need ***JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet*** 
when you are returning Json to your request